# how to get timezone by standard timezone name in php

Tags: php, datetime

I have the standard timezone names stored in my db and i want to get the respective timezones for the names in php, i have searched a lot but did not get a way, tried with the `listAbbreviations()` but it did not work for the case, suppose the below example

```
<?php
  $name = 'India Standard Time';

  function someFunctionORanyCode($name){
    //code here
  }

  $outPutTimeZone = someFunctionORanyCode($name);
 echo "timezone is: ".$outPutTimeZone;
```

**output: timezone is Asia/Kolkata**

can any body help me to achieve it plz

Comment: There is no magical converter as I dont think there is anything _Standard_ about the string `India Standard Time` You will have to write your own converter

Comment: You need to add your own conditions for that

Comment: Why do you need this anyway? If you are using PHP, you can get the time zones in a number of ways and you can even change the UTC date and time to local date and time without using timezone at all:https://www.tinywebhut.com/convert-utc-date-and-time-to-local-date-and-time-without-time-zones-37

Comment: actually i have the standard time zones name stored in db and i want the timezone for my code

Comment: I'm not aware of any kind of converter like you've asked but the purpose of the time zones is not clear. You didn't tell why and for what purpose you are trying to achieve this.

Comment: purpose is only i have the names stored in my old db tables which i can not modify as these are using now my requirement is to get the timezone for the respective names stored in db